# Clean stack trace for logs

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework2

I have several classes (a, b, c and so on) that extends an abstract class called mother. All the "sons" use the method "save":

```
<?php

class mother {
    public function save() {
        echo "Mother saves!\n";
        debug_print_backtrace();
    }
}

class a extends mother {
    public function save() {
        echo "Calling save from A\n";
        parent::save();
    }
}

$test = new a;
$test->save();

?>
```

If you run this code, the result of debug_print_backtrace is very clean and it is exactly what I need:

```
#0 mother->save() called at [/home/xfiddlec/public_html/main/code_44364601.php:13] #1 a->save() called at [/home/xfiddlec/public_html/main/code_44364601.php:18]
```

The problem is, if you are using a framework (Im using Zend2), the stack trace is over a 1MB, a huge string. If there a way I can limit the trace coverage? For my application having the file, the line and the name of the class that extended mother is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand the question right the answer is simple.  Throw and catch an exception

```
try{
    throw new Exception();
}catch( Exception $e ){
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

It's a neat trick I use for debugging. Also you can just get the trace as an array and use slice or whatnot on it.